# Why hover in flex or grid is not working?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use flex and grid in a horizontal menu bar and hover is not working. It works fine without grid or flex. I am trying that if it can work with grid or flex.

HTML:

```
<div class="hmenu">
 <ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
 </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.hmenu{ display: grid; grid-auto-columns: auto; background-color: #015491; margin-top: 5px; }
.hmenu > ul { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }
.hmenu > ul > li { display: flex; width: auto; height: 100%; background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #788cff, #b4c8ff); border: #A67BC6 solid; padding: 10px; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin-right: 50px; }
.hmenu > a { font-size: 15px; line-height: 100%; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; font-family: sans-serif "Avenir Light"; font-weight: strong 300; color: #FFFFFF; }
.hmenu a:hover { box-shadow: 0px 16px 22px 2px rgba(51,51,51,0.2); transform: translateY(-20px); background-color: #73b3e7; }
```

Comment: you have no <a> elements which are required in tour selector (.hmenu a:hover) - either add <a>elements or change the selector to the li (.hmenu ul li:hover)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<li><a href="...">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">C</a></li>
 </ul>
```

it will works now!!

Answer (score 0):

a:hover is only applicable for A HREF elements, and in your code you don't have them.

Place A HREF elements:

```
<div class="hmenu">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="...">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">B</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">C</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

or use .hmenu :hover instead of .hmenu a:hover.

```
.hmenu{ display: grid; grid-auto-columns: auto; background-color: #015491; margin-top: 5px; }
.hmenu > ul { display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }
.hmenu > ul > li { display: flex; width: auto; height: 100%; background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #788cff, #b4c8ff); border: #A67BC6 solid; padding: 10px; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin-right: 50px; }
.hmenu > a { font-size: 15px; line-height: 100%; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; font-family: sans-serif "Avenir Light"; font-weight: strong 300; color: #FFFFFF; }
.hmenu :hover { box-shadow: 0px 16px 22px 2px rgba(51,51,51,0.2); transform: translateY(-20px); background-color: #73b3e7; }
```

In addition you should use .hmenu a instead of .hmenu > a, or perhaps use .hmenu > ul > li > a ... but as it is, it will not work.